# Using jQuery to find current visible element and update navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, visible

First time user here. I am usually capable of finding answers for questions but I am having a difficult time figuring this one out.

**The Goal:**

I have a single page layout with a sidebar navigation that when clicked will scroll down to an element on the page. However, if the user just scrolls down the page to a specific element `#id` I want the corresponding link in the navigation to become `.active`. The navigation link and the corresponding element share the same value via `element#id` and `a[name]`.

**Similar to:** [NikeBetterWorld.com](http://www.nikebetterworld.com/)

**HTML Example below:**

```
<nav>
    <a name="value">Link</a>
</nav>

<section id="value">
    content goes here
</section>
```

Obviously, there's more sections, links, elements, etc. But this is the gist of it. So when the user scrolls down to `section#value` the `a[value]` will have gained the class active.

I found an answer on here earlier that has helped somewhat but I am still having some issues. [See this link for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230880/jquery-javascript-find-first-visible-element-after-scroll).

**Current Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();
    var cutoffRange = cutoff + 200;

    // Find current section and highlight nav menu
    var curSec = $.find('.current');
    var curID = $(curSec).attr('id');
    var curNav = $.find('a[name='+curID+']');
    $(curNav).addClass('active');

    $('.section').each(function(){
        if ($(this).offset().top > cutoff && $(this).offset().top < cutoffRange) {
            $('.section').removeClass('current')
            $(this).addClass('current');
            return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on screen
        }
    });
});
```

**The Problem:**

While the above code works to an extent I am running into one big issue. I am having trouble getting an entire element to stay `.current`. If the top of the element goes out of the window it will lose the class. I fixed that by adding a range for new elements, but now when the user scrolls upwards the previous element will not gain the class `.current` until the top of the element reaches the top of the window. I would prefer it if a dominant portion of the window, when visible, gained the `.current` class.

Any help, ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is one of the coolest websites I've ever seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want to check the bottom edge of the section and not the top.  Try this and remove the range all together:

```
if($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > cutoff){
```

EDIT: Created a fiddle.  I think this is what you're describing.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdzTW/

Comment: Additionally you could add a bit of a buffer to `cutoff` to make the class change a bit before the entire thing is off screen  http://jsfiddle.net/pdzTW/1/

Comment: Awesome man, this works perfect! Thanks a lot! Here I am trying to use math to figure out ranges and what not when I completely forgot about using `.height()`.  Just one of those things where you start looking at the problem all wrong.

Answer (score 2):

yeeeahhh! got the solution!

I just change from:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(section).offset().top) {
```

to

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + 80 >= $(section).offset().top) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use jQuerys "filter" function to return the current section.

```
$currSection = $('section').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var offset = $this.offset().top;
    var view = winHeight / 2;

    return scrollTop >= offset - view && offset + ($this.outerHeight() - view) >= scrollTop;
});
```

Wrap it in a scroll listener like:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // here we go ...
});
```

Thats it.

Comment: what is winHeight?