# How do I know which part user is viewing on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built a long page website, so I decide to build a sidebar to navigate user. I want to know which part my user is viewing, so I can change the sidebar css to active or hightlight.

Is there any js or jquery function I can use to get which part user is viewing?

Comment: check out `$(window).scroll()` `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: To go to some part he must have clicked or selected some option target that only

Comment: interesting, can you show image before active and after active....

Comment: Since you want to know where you are in the page you'll want to use position() - https://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: If he gets there by clicking a named anchor, you can check location.hash - but unless you bind to scroll event and watch it, you lose him when he scrolls.

Comment: I get my solution through [this Question][1], Thank you for your help again!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230880/jquery-javascript-find-first-visible-element-after-scroll

Answer (score 0):

There are some jquery plugins you can use, Ex: Waypoints, Jquery Inview . Using this plugin you can change the class name for sidebar when the user scrolls into some part of the page or section. Simple solution is using  **$(window).scrollTop()**

```
     $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            //change the class name for sidebar         
                    } else {
            //revert the class name for sidebar
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my page is dynamic, the position of each content is variable. Can u help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I get my solution through [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230880/jquery-javascript-find-first-visible-element-after-scroll).

I can calculate the pixel from the top to the current viewpoint, and then find out the first  element's id.

Thank for your help again!