# On scrolling manually capture by alerting its id/class when div which is within container comes at its topmost position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to capture the event when div which is placed within container reaches to the topmost position using jquery (without using scrollspy) 
Require pure javascript/jquery logic

Please refer the attached screenshot:
https://snag.gy/xoPVv5.jpg

Wherein the below part boxes are placed within container.
When i scroll within that container, as div comes to the topmost position, please alert it's specific id/class.

Comment: Its not a freelance site :) , I think you should try something, then any one can help to you in finding your problem/issue.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230880/jquery-javascript-find-first-visible-element-after-scroll